# Inconsistent behaviour while using "foreign" as a variable / binding name

Tags: haskell, elm

I'm trying to compile the Elm compiler from source and have run into a strange problem. I've managed to make it build via `stack build` successfully. However, when I try `stack ghci` it fails at a number of places where `foreign` has been used as a variable/binding name. For example:

```
/Users/saurabhnanda/projects/compiler/builder/src/File/Compile.hs:142:50: error:
    parse error on input ‘foreign’
    |
142 | makeImports project (Plan.Info _ _ _ clean dirty foreign) =
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^
Failed, 141 modules loaded.
```

It seems that `foreign` is indeed a [reserved keyword](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#foreign). What explains this behaviour, i.e. working in `stack build` but throwing a parse-error in `stack ghci`?

Comment: Maybe the ffi / foreignfunctioninterface extension is somehow set by `stack ghci`

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? 8.4/8.6 don't let me have variables named `foreign` at all.

Comment: @Alec 8.4.3 last time I checked.

Answer (score 1):

`foreign` is not used anymore in Elm source code, see https://github.com/elm/compiler/pull/1961.